# What does the * prefix mean in nativescript-vue?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript, nativescript-vue

I've seen multiple code samples using *v-show or in GridLayouts I've seen rows="*,*,*".  Is this just a shorthand for auto?  Or similar to @ in regular vue.js?

Comment: I'm pretty sure * is not used with v-show, but if you share the sample you are looking at that might help. You use * with Grid Layout, it means take as much space available - https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts/layout-containers#gridlayout

Comment: I saw this in an example on the nativescript vue marketplace -  <Label *v-show="isLoggingIn" text="Forgot your password?" class="login-label" @tap="forgotPassword()"></Label>

But it looks now like it may just be a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*" takes all available space, "auto" takes just the space it needs.